# Creating an image from data not in grayscale

Tags: image-processing

I can Import data from excel and create a gray-scale image using

```
Image[data, "Real"]
```

But I want to change from grayscale and as an example use red as the color

Comment: Look the option `ColorSpace` under `Image` in the documentation.

Comment: @Sektor Gray is gray, regardless of color space.

Comment: @Pickett Oh, I missed the grayscale part :D

Comment: Please add some actual `data`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}];
ColorCombine[{Image[data], Image[0 data], Image[0 data]}]
```

[image]

This creates an RGB image which has the data as the Red channel, and all zeros in the Green and Blue channels. By weighting them differently you can get any color you wish. For instance, you can get yellow:

```
ColorCombine[{Image[data], Image[data], Image[0 data]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For this purpose you can use the function [`Colorize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Colorize.html) which is sufficient even for fancy coloring. Let's make some examples with a B&W photo

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/397vv.png"]
```

[image: Eye]

If you simply want to use the gray channel as one or more color channels you use

```
Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> Function[gray, RGBColor[0, gray, gray]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same works of course with other color functions

```
Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> Function[gray, Hue[0.6, 1 - gray, gray]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With the built-in color schemes of *Mathematica* you can get more fancy looks and the usage is even simpler

```
Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you mix everything together

```
Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> 
  Function[gray, RGBColor @@ (gray*List @@ ColorData["BrightBands", gray])]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

If you have a worksheet like this one:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could do:

```
id = Import["C:\\test.xlsx"];
ColorCombine[Image /@ ({#, # 0, # 0} &@id[[1]])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note for wicked users:Yes, I always store my photos in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

There are many functions that generate `RGBColor[r,g,b]` and these can often be helpful even for purposes such as this. `Blend` figures out the correct red, green, and blue components and then I extract them using a rule, putting them into the required format `{r,g,b}`.

Another thing worth noting is that I use an anonymous function that I give that property `Listable` so that it is applied on all elements of the matrix automatically.

```
col = Function[x, Blend[{Red, Black}, x] /. RGBColor[r_, g_, b_] :> {r, g, b}, Listable];
Image[col@data]
```